# Introductions to Algorithms Ch-11 Q-11.2.4

Tags: algorithm, hash, hashtable

I was reading about hash table, hash functions and asymptotic complexity of their operations but i stuck up here.

> Suggest how to allocate and deallocate storage for elements within the hash table
>   itself by linking all unused slots into a free list. Assume that one slot can store
>   a flag and either one element plus a pointer or two pointers. **All dictionary and
>   free-list operations should run in O(1) expected time.** Does the free list need to be
>   doubly linked, or does a singly linked free list suffice?

Here all thing is clear but one thing is still confusing. It says

> All dictionary and free-list operations should run in O(1) expected time.

Delete,Insert will definitely run in O(1) **but how could Search operation run in O(1) time?**

**Looked in CLRS solution**, but there it was written that

> Search is unmodified, so it has expected time O(1).

What possibly would this mean as Search operation was never having O(1) running time.

Comment: " as Search operation was never having O(1) running time..." Ok, then what was the running time of the search operation?

Comment: Well it is O(1+x) where x=n/m, n will be total no of keys and m will be number of keys that can be stored in hash table. Or in worse case it will be O(n) as we will have to search through the whole list the pointer is pointing to.

Comment: I don't have the book, so I don't know how this hash table is organized, but normally n << m so that x < 1 and search is O(1) on average.

Comment: This book consider a Universe set(U) with all the keys, say n and a dictionary (hash table) with small set of keys, say m where slot in this dictionary is alloted to the key k of U on the basis of hash functions used, say h(k). So here n>>m and x would be close to n. For collision resolution they have used linked list, hence search operation is taking O(1+x) or take it ~O(n)

Comment: @abhi_awake Not sure what is your background (math?). Could you clarify what you mean with "Search operation", do you mean search in a well configured hash table, or search in a linked list, or something else? Search in a well configured hash table is O(1) in most cases. For details, maybe you want to check Wikipedia.

Comment: @ThomasMueller Sir in a linked list because how would you know whether a key is in a hash table or not without going through a linked list that the slot in the hash table is pointing to??

Comment: @abhi_awake Sure, in a linked list of size n, lookup is O(n). But a hash table of size n, there are no linked lists of size n (if done correctly). With high probability, there are only short linked lists. That's the reason why on average, hash tables (not linked lists) have an expected lookup time of O(1).